# Exceptions with Struts Tag

Tags: jakarta-ee, exception, struts2, valuestack

I am getting below exception with Netbeans 7.0.1 and Struts 2.2.3
Its quite weird as the jsp pages which used to work suddenly starts giving below exception. Mostly,it looks like problem with deployment or library configuration. Please help.

> WARNING: StandardWrapperValve[jsp]: PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.ValueStack.findValue(Ljava/lang/String;Z)Ljava/lang/Object;
>       at org.apache.struts2.components.Component.findValue(Component.java:255)
>       at org.apache.struts2.components.ActionError.evaluateExtraParams(ActionError.java:73)
>       at org.apache.struts2.components.UIBean.evaluateParams(UIBean.java:856)
>       at org.apache.struts2.components.UIBean.end(UIBean.java:510)
>       at org.apache.struts2.views.jsp.ComponentTagSupport.doEndTag(ComponentTagSupport.java:42)
>       at org.apache.jsp.jsp.user.user_jsp._jspx_meth_s_actionerror_0(user_jsp.java:115)
>       at org.apache.jsp.jsp.user.user_jsp._jspService(user_jsp.java:84)
>       at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:111)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
>       at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:403)
>       at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:492)
>       at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:378)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1539)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:343)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
>       at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:428)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:98)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:91)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:162)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:174)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:828)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:725)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1019)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

I am using below Lib:

[image]

Comment: can you deploy your application starting from cleaning everything and building fresh as well deploying

Comment: I tried have tried all combination (undeployed, cleaned, built and deployed). I even tried restarting netbeans and taking again from SVN.

Comment: try to make a new project and copy paste your code

Comment: it worked..dont know what kind of issue is that...